# How can I reference a parameter within a designated initializer?

Tags: c, designated-initializer

I want to add the value of a parameter to another parameter within a designated initializer, without having to define a separate variable to hold that value. Is this possible?

```
typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
} point;

int main() {
  point p = {
    .x = 1,
    .y = x + 2 // I want to reference .x
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.  The evaluation order of expressions in an initializer are not evaluated in any particular order, so there's no guarantee that `.x` will be set to 1 before `.y` is set to `.x + 2`.

This is spelled out in section 6.7.9p23 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The  evaluations  of  the  initialization  list  expressions  are
> indeterminately  sequenced  with respect   to   one   another   and
> thus   the   order   in   which   any   side   effects   occur   is
> unspecified.<sup>152)</sup>

Where footnote 152 states:

> In particular, the evaluation order need not be the same as the order
> of subobject initialization.